# using Less with React.js and Antd

Tags: reactjs, less

I'm trying to use a Less file to modify the styling of an antd component. I made a simple [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/antd-styling-input?file=src%2FApp.js) to demonstrate. I'm trying to change the size of the antd Input to 400px but can't.

Read up on Less and Ant Design, no luck.
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Have you followed the docs? https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme, you just imported the style in `.less` file and hoping to override it, there are different selector names for antd component to begin with.

Comment: @DennisVash I did, but that seems to be for modifying the theme, rather than styling of specific components? Also if I don't use Less but instead plain CSS it works fine [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/antd-styling-input-abandoning-less?file=src%2Fapp.css)